# How do I download from gitorious?

Tags: git, gitorious

How to clone projects from [gitorious.org](http://gitorious.org)?

I'd like to clone http://gitorious.org/lightopenid

UPDATE: this project is moved away, example of existing project: https://gitorious.org/dbus-cplusplus/mainline

Comment: Calling it "a git hub" is probably not the best choice of words, since GitHub is a specific git hosting service. You can interact with a git repository hosted on gitorious in the same way as any publicly accessible git repository, plus through the web interface.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That page conveniently has a URL on it for you! All you need to do is install git on your system and clone that repository:

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid.git
```

Or, if you're not actually planning on working with the repository, it looks like you can click on source tree, then there's an option on the right sidebar to download the current version of the source tarball.

Comment: @Webnet: I almost didn't find it either - was hunting around just on the front page.

Comment: You can also download it using https:
`git clone https://gitorious.org/dbus-cplusplus/mainline.git`