# How to get qtCreator 2.5 Rc sources

Tags: git, gitorious

here: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator are the sources for qtCreator 2.5 RC. How can I download them on my machine? I have Git installed.

Comment: There's documentation about how to do that _right on the page you link to_.

Comment: Gitorious can provide the source code for 2.5 RC directly as tar.gz http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/archive-tarball/v2.5.0-rc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following post: [How do I download from gitorious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195723/how-do-i-download-from-gitorious)

In your case this sould be something like

`git clone git://gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator.git`